# Why the Bluetooth button is disabled? (window 8)

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I want to connect to a Bluetooth device but I found that my Bluetooth enable button is disable and I can not turn it ON.

I have checked the device manager, and it shows that it is working properly.

What can I do to turn it ON? I am using window 8.

[image: button]

**update info: Bluetooth Driver**

I am using Samsung laptop

[image: driver]

**This problem is solved. I can now add the Bluetooth device even with the Bluetooth button disable... and have no reason and explanation, it is a mystery....**

Answer (score 1):

I will try answering this question without having almost no information about your Setup.
In order to edit this Post i would like to know if your Computer is Laptop or Desktop, if it is a laptop, What brand it is, and what model. Does your bluetooth worked before?

Ok There are many possibilities and reasons that this issue may have been caused.

1. **Wrong Drivers**. if you accidentaly install Windows 7 Drivers to a Windows 8 Application you will get this outcome. Please double check your Drivers Compatibility.
2. **Disabled bluetooth Device**. Considering that you are in a Laptop there are some FN + Key combinations that disables your Bluetooth adapter. Please search for the Antenna Icon on your Keyboard and press it along with FN, to ensure that is not disabled accidentaly by you.
3. **Driver Collision**. You might have some other Drivers installed to your computer that they are collising with Bluetooth Drivers, such as (MotionJOY Bluetooth Drivers) or PS3XC Drivers. If you do have any of these applications, uninstall them to get your Bluetooth to work.

Comment: There are 3 listed driver and I would guess it is using the first one.

Comment: Is it a laptop?

Comment: yes. is a samsung laptop

Comment: Can you provide me the Model of your Laptop?

Comment: surprisingly I solve the problem.... I can scan now scan the Bluetooth device even the button is not enabled... And I just do not know why....

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the Bluetooth driver
2. Make sure your Bluetooth setting is set to `allow Bluetooth device to find this computer`
3. Add Bluetooth device and scan your device
4. If you found your window app showing the Bluetooth button is disabled but anyhow you still manage to scan and add your device. **Ignore the "button disabled" problem**. Update your window 8.